# Unable to read system property in a static block

Tags: java, servlets, junit

I'm facing an issue setting a system property defined in a servlet from the JUnit test. My servlet initialization looks like this:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4306648703337839989L;

    private static final String CLASS_NAME = MyServlet.class.getName();

    public static final String PROPERTY_NAME = CLASS_NAME + ".myProperty";

    private static final long DEFAULT_PROPERTY_VALUE = 120000;

    private static final long PROPERTY_VALUE;

    static
    {
        long propValue = DEFAULT_PROPERTY_VALUE;
        final String propertyStr = java.lang.System.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME);
        if (propertyStr != null)
        {
            propValue = Long.parseLong(propertyStr);
        }
        PROPERTY_VALUE = propValue;
    }
}
```

Now my JUnit test sets the property value to say 5000 as follows:

```
@Test
public void testMyServlet()
{
    java.lang.System.setProperty(MyServlet.PROPERTY_NAME, "5000");
    <test>
}
```

When I run the test, the value of the static final field 'PROPERTY_VALUE' is resolved to 120000 rather than 5000. So obviously the servlet init happens before the test and that's why the value of the field is already resolved to the default value before the test can set the system property. I'm looking for suggestions to get around this so that my test can set that system property to 5000.

Thanks!

EDIT: Solution

I was able to get the test working by setting the system property to 5000 in two ways:

Solution 1: Set the system property in a static block at the very top of the test class.

```
public class MyTest
{
    static
    {
        java.lang.System.setProperty("com.servlets.MyServlet.myProperty", "5000");
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyServlet()
    {
         <my test>
    }
}
```

Solution 2: Set the system property in the JUnit test itself but using the property key as the full canonical name.

```
public class MyTest
{
    @Test
    public void testMyServlet()
    {
        java.lang.System.setProperty("com.servlets.MyServlet.myProperty", "5000");
         <my test>
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would `PROPERTY_VALUE` be set to `5000` when you're setting `PROPERTY_NAME` to `5000`?

Comment: I'm using System.getProperty() to get the property string. If it is present then I want to override the default value

Comment: It seems that you are initializing the property in a static class block. This block is executed when the class is being loaded into memory which is before your test execution. Setting a system property won't have any effect as `PROPERTY_VALUE` has been already set.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the test working by setting the system property to 5000 in two ways:

Solution 1: Set the system property in a static block at the very top of the test class.

```
public class MyTest
{
    static
    {
        java.lang.System.setProperty("com.servlets.MyServlet.myProperty", "5000");
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyServlet()
    {
         <my test>
    }
}
```

Solution 2: Set the system property in the JUnit test itself but using the property key as the full canonical name.

```
public class MyTest
{
    @Test
    public void testMyServlet()
    {
        java.lang.System.setProperty("com.servlets.MyServlet.myProperty", "5000");
         <my test>
    }
}
```